# Suppose I have a StringIO file. How can I use python-magic to check its file type?

Tags: python, string, file, mime-types, stringio

```
import StringIO
import magic

m = magic.Magic()
thefile = StringIO.StringIO(request.raw_post_data)  # I got this from Django. ajax file uploader.
```

what now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...should be as easy as:

```
 >>> m.from_buffer(thefile.read(1024))
'PDF document, version 1.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to use the from_buffer method.

```
m.from_buffer(theFile)
```